# What's the point of "NOT NULL DEFAULT '' "?

Tags: mysql

I've seen this on a lot of fields on a DB from a project I've been working on, where a column will be defined not null, but will have an empty string as the default. what's the point of doing this? If you will allow an empty string, why not just allow a field to be null?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

NULLs have special behavior: comparing anything with a NULL gives you back a `NULL`, which is something else than `false` or `0`. It means "unknown".

For example, take this table:

```
 user_id | gender
------------------
 1       | NULL
 2       | 'M'
 3       | 'F'
 4       | 'F'
```

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE gender = 'M'` will return 1 row, as expected

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE gender != 'M'` will return 2 rows, NOT 3 rows.

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE gender != 'M' OR gender IS NULL` will return the expected 3 rows.

---

Edit: For some applications, using `0` (or, God forbid, another "magic number") instead of `NULL` is not even advisable (units or exact values are not relevant in this example):

```
 Date       | Temperature 
--------------------------
 2010-01-01 | 10          
 2010-01-02 | 4
 2010-01-03 | 0
 2010-01-04 | -22
 2010-01-05 | -45
 2010-01-06 | NULL
 2010-01-07 | -34
```

Here, the `NULL` on Jan 6th means "value unknown" - maybe because the temperature was so low that the thermometer probe stopped responding. However, it's a completely different meaning than Jan 3rd, when the temperature was `0`, that is, 0 degrees.

Also, as @Bill Karwin mentions, NULLs behave specially in aggregate functions (`COUNT`,`SUM`,`AVG` etc.): calculating `AVG(Temperature)` on the above data would give you `-14.5`, as the NULL row is ignored.

Comment: I had no idea null would behave that way! I'm accepting this one as this is a crystal clear example of why to use not null.

Comment: +1 It's also worth mentioning that NULL is skipped for most aggregate functions.  You probably don't want to count NULL as zero for `SELECT AVG(Temperature)` because it would skew your result.  So NULL does have a useful purpose.

Comment: @dr01: Thank you :)

Answer (score 11):

null and "" are not the same thing, so there is no contradiction here.

What the semantic meaning of null/"" is depends on the individual and is often a "religious" issue. To some people in some schemas, of course, they may be the same, but they don't have to be. For example, a "" might mean "I explicitly asked the user for input, and they chose to enter nothing" while a null might mean "I never even asked for input".

Comment: The comment about it potentially being a religious issue raises a point - a developers background and experience may play a part. The following examples behave differently in different languages: '' == null, "" == null, 0 == null, "" === null. With some you have explicit type checks (like String.Empty or === operators, or strcmp()) and it's easy to get things wrong. The distinction is much clearer in some languages than others - some scripting languages in particular make life harder than others (e.g. Perl is particularly subtly evil in this regard).

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between a null value and an empty string - at least in SQL.

```
SELECT LENGTH('tata');
4

SELECT LENGTH(NULL);
NULL

SELECT LENGTH('tata')-LENGTH('');
4

SELECT LENGTH('tata')-LENGTH(NULL);
NULL
```

Comment: "at least in MySQL" => "at least in SQL"

Answer (score 1):

Most programming languages that interact with a database don't natively support a NULL that works the way it does in a database.  For example in C#, null <> DbNull.Value.  In VB most data types couldn't cope with null semantics, e.g. you couldn't store a null in a Date, or an Int, etc.  By reducing the number of nulls the client programs see, the less headaches there are.  In the case of VB, the closes thing that means null for strings is Empty, which is something closer to not-initialized, not quite the same meaning as NULL in the sense of a "not known"

Answer (score 0):

Because sometimes, on some languages, a "select" query would give you the *string* **NULL**, and you would have to check if it's a real string with content "NULL" or it is really null.

With "" it's easiest (IMHO)

Comment: I hope I misunderstood that... what are these languages you're referring to?

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is not the case.  In SQL, you can test "WHERE MyField IS NULL", which is different to "WHERE MyField = 'NULL'".  When you compare the results in your programming language, there is normally a way of checking database nulls.  In .NET, database null is represented as DBNull.Value.

Answer (score 0):

We do not allow nulls because programmatically accessing a field from a datatable with a DBnull value causes an exception, while an empty string has a value and therefore does not error.

Comment: Is this specific to some interface? Accessing a null value in MySQL doesn't cause any problems.

Comment: I believe he's referencing the consumption of the field on the application side. VB Classic / .NET interpret the NULL field as DBNull, which could result in an exception when cast without first checking that the value is not DBNull.

Comment: Thanks Stacy, Yes this is what I was suggesting. If you loaded your data into a Dataset or datatable in an application and wanted to assign the value of a nullable field to a variable, you first need to check if the field is DBNull. Ensuring the value is not null, you can safely access the field without checking or the possibility of an exception.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Piskvor mentioned, this practice is also there so as to prevent some potential NullPointerExceptions in the application logic when populating beans/objects etc. after reading from DB