# Difference between value = ""; and value = NULL; in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

What is the difference between `value = NULL;` and `value = "";` in PHP ?

Am facing wierd response as if I set `value = "";` than I get empty array response from database which is what am supposed to get but if I set `value = NULL;` than I get empty string response from mysql database instead of empty array response.

I am not sure  why this is the case. Any Suggestions !!!

Comment: Is this question about PHP, or about SQL databases? If it is about PHP, how does the database remark factor in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

empty strings and NULL are treated differently in MySQL. I had a similar question about this issue:

[why use NOT NULL default = ''?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723367/whats-the-point-of-not-null-default)

You have 2 solutions here:

- Set the database field(s) you are checking to NOT NULL default '' or something similar.
- rewrite your queries so that check both cases. ex: 'where field = '' OR field IS NULL'

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

[Working with NULL Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)

> The NULL value can be surprising until
>   you get used to it. Conceptually, NULL
>   means “a missing unknown value” and it
>   is treated somewhat differently from
>   other values. To test for NULL, you
>   cannot use the arithmetic comparison
>   operators such as =, <, or <>. *Use the IS NULL and IS NOT NULL operators instead.*

Comment: No, but it is MySQL, which is also tagged in the question, with no specification of which the question applies to. Up-voted to reduce the karma-hit (and because it's a good answer, obviously).

Answer (score 0):

Value = NULL sets the variable to nothing, basically. Whereas Value = "" sets it to a blank string and while a blank string might look like nothing, it technically is a value of sorts. NULL and "" are both different values.

Comment: They actually are quite different http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php :

$var = "";

is_null($var) is false.

Comment: Ok, your right:

<?php

if ('' == null) echo " '' == null ";
if ('' === null) echo " '' === null ";

Outputs:
'' == null